# how to get each unique value from access database column and add to combobox items

Tags: database, combobox, ms-access-2007

I am not professional but i am trying to learn VB.net. I am making a project where i am stuck where i want to get each unique value from a column in access database and add it to my combobox. Can anybody help me ??

```
Private Sub showItems()

    Dim comm As OleDbCommand
    Dim commStr As String = "SELECT Item_Name FROM Add_Items WHERE (Item_Name <> '"
    Dim RD As OleDbDataReader

    conn = New OleDbConnection(connStr)
    conn.Open()

    If cbItemname.Items.Count = 0 Then
        comm = New OleDbCommand("Select Item_Name from Add_Items", conn)
        RD = comm.ExecuteReader
        While RD.Read
            cbItemname.Items.Add(RD.GetString(0))
        End While
    End If


    For Each i As Object In cbItemname.Items
        comm = New OleDbCommand(commStr & i & "')", conn)
        RD = comm.ExecuteReader
        While RD.Read
            cbItemname.Items.Add(RD.GetString(0))
            Exit While
        End While
    Next

    conn.Close()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
comm = New OleDbCommand("Select DISTINCT Item_Name from Add_Items", conn)
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/HV080760568.aspx

You can get this error because your database table name is incorrect. Make sure you are in the Tables tab and check the name of the table. DISTINCT and UNIQUE(for MySQL) is correct solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I followed instructions given by vipul. It was working nicely and i made some more private subs for brands and Models and it suddenly stopped working. Now, when my form loads from previous parent form it hangs.

```
 Private Sub showItems()

    Dim comm As OleDbCommand
    Dim commStr As String = "SELECT DISTINCT Item_Name from Add_Items"
    Dim ReadData As OleDbDataReader

    itemnamecombo.Items.Clear()
    ItemChkboxList.Items.Clear()

    Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection(ConnStr)
        conn.Open()
        comm = New OleDbCommand(commStr, conn)
        ReadData = comm.ExecuteReader

        While ReadData.Read
            itemnamecombo.Items.Add(ReadData.GetString(0))
            ItemChkboxList.Items.Add(ReadData.GetString(0))

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
    If itemnamecombo.Items.Count <> 0 Then
        itemnamecombo.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I found the solution myself i just had to remove he last if clause